# Calling code on a push Twitter notification

Tags: python-3.x, twitter

Is there an API provided by Twitter to call back some code on a push notification?

I would like to execute some code when someone I am following is tweeting.

Looked at TweePy but it does not seem to implement callbacks for push notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use the streaming API (with TweePy) and filter for the accounts you follow e.g.:

`stream.filter(follow=['@user1',...])`

You get the users you follow by calling: `GET friends/list` [Twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-friends-list)

You can then call any callback you like per tweet that is found... works but needs a permanently running (small ressource consuming) process...

There also seems to be something like the [Account Activity API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/enterprise/account-activity-api/overview) which looks good but seems to be "enterprise" ... or premium [this page](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tutorials/getting-started-with-the-account-activity-api) does not mention enterprise needed...(now premium ??)

But I personally don't know what you need for premium or enterprise access...

Comment: Premium and enterprise access requires a monthly payment, I think.